# In drupal read css file and add it's content as inline in "page.tpl.php"

Tags: drupal-6

I want to read the CSS files and add its contents in "page.tpl.php" as inline. I am using Drupal 6. Anyone have idea how can I do that?

- For example a CSS file called '`style.css`' and '`default.css`'

Answer (score 0):

why don`t you put them in theme.info file ?
Then you do not need to render inline.

One more way , you need to include css using link tag.